# Cannot convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult'

Tags: c#

I have this C# code for my unit test and it has syntax error at `result as OkObjectResult`

```
Task<IActionResult> result = controller.Create(Id);

var okObjectResult = result as OkObjectResult;
```

How to I convert from type `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>'` to `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult'`?

Comment: Can you try `var okObjectResult = result.Result as OkObjectResult;`?

Comment: `IActionResult result = await controller.Create(Id);`

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks. It works.

Comment: The type `Task<T>` and `OkObjectResult` are two unrelated types with root type `object` as the only common ancestor. The actual problem should be about how to get and convert the result of a Task<T> object to another type, as above comments suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all make sure that `OkObjectResult` implements `IActionResult`.
The important thing is however is to take note that you can not convert directly between a `Task` of said class to a `Concrete` type of said class. In your case you have `Task<T>`, you can not directly convert it to a type of it generic argument directly.
In the comments @Enigmativity suggests that you get `Task.Result as OkObjectResult`. Even though it should work, it may end up with deadlocks (I see that you are working on .net core which does not have synchronization context therefore not likely to end up in a deadlock).

My advice is to go async all the way.

```
var result = await controller.Create(Id);
var okObjectResult = result as OkObjectResult;
```

Answer (score 3):

try to add `async` to method and `await` before `_controller` solved my same issue